# Neo4j Cypher: Behavior of skip/limit with allshortestpath?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How does skip and limit behave with allshortestpath? Is there a way I can  paginate the paths returned from allShortestpaths?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SKIP` and `LIMIT` are unrelated to paths.  A path is just a type of object that can be returned, like a collection, a map, a node, a relationship.

So sure, SKIP and LIMIT will work to paginate paths.  The tricky part there is that paths are hard to compare to one another, so pagination may be less useful there.  Normally to paginate, you'd `ORDER BY` something.   Say for example you'd return customer first names and last names, paginated, ordered by last name.

I don't think there's a generally useful comparator to `ORDER BY` paths other than something like length.  You'd have to compute that separately, for example:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[*]->(b)
RETURN p, length(p) as pathLen
ORDER BY pathLen
LIMIT 10
SKIP 10
```

(That would be page 2 of a list of paths, ordered by length)

Here, `pathLen` is a standin for a useful comparator.  If you were going to paginate paths, I'd think about a comparator that makes the most sense, maybe not length.